# How can I store an array or list of Strings in a PyTable?

Tags: python, database, hdf5, pytables

For example, I have the following table description.  In SpectrumL, I would like to store a (spectrogram) I do not know the exact size yet.  Similarly, I would like to store some tags (which will be strings) and their size will vary by record.  However, when I try to execute the build statement for this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Passing an incorrect value to a table column. Expected a Col (or subclass) instance and got: "StringAtom(itemsize=20, shape=(), dflt='')". Please make use of the Col(), or descendant, constructor to properly initialize columns.
```

The statement I am executing is:

```
h5file = tables.open_file("foo.h5", mode = "w", title = "Datastore")
group = h5file.create_group("/", 'metadata', 'General MetaData')
table =  h5file.create_table(group, 'footer', hdf5Pull.BuildTable, "information")
```

The table statement class is:

```
   class BuildTable(IsDescription):
        artist_id = StringCol(100)
        tags = StringAtom(itemsize = 20)
        spectrumL = Float64Atom((5000, 1))
        spectrumR = Float64Atom((5000, 1))
        frequency = Float64Atom((5000, 1))
```

Might anyone be able to help take a look at this?  I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the documentation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message contains all the information. You have to use `Col` or subclasses but you are providing `Atoms`.

The table statement must be something like this:

```
class BuildTable(IsDescription):
        artist_id = StringCol(100)
        tags = StringCol(itemsize = 20)
        spectrumL = Float64Col(shape=(5000, 1))
        spectrumR = Float64Col(shape=(5000, 1))
        frequency = Float64Col(shape=(5000, 1))
```

If you want to store multiple values in a single cell you have to rely on multidimensional cells (see [here](https://pytables.github.io/usersguide/tutorials.html#multidimensional-table-cells-and-automatic-sanity-checks)).